# Incrementing and decrementing index in insertion sort

Tags: python, list, sorting, insertion

In the code below, I am not sure what the i -= 1 is doing. I know it's decrementing the index by 1 each time it runs through the for loop but exactly how is that helping to sort?

```
def insertionSort(ls):
    for i in range(1, len(ls)):
        while ls[i-1] > ls[i] and i > 0:
            ls[i], ls[i-1] = ls[i-1], ls[i]
            i -= 1
            print(i)
    return ls

listA = [5,5,3,9,1,4,9,7,3]
result = insertionSort(listA)
print(result)
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not helping?

Comment: Decrementing i in this way is functionally correct but definitely makes the code unnecessarily difficult to understand as it gets reset at each iteration of the range. Better to use a different variable for clarity

Answer (score 1):

The i-= 1 iterates i from it's current value (set by the outer loop) downwards until the current element you're sorting is in the correct place.

e.g.

```
def insertionSort(ls):
    for i in range(1, len(ls)):
        print(f"Outer loop. i is set to {i}")
        print(ls)
        while ls[i-1] > ls[i] and i > 0:
            ls[i], ls[i-1] = ls[i-1], ls[i]
            i -= 1
            print(i)
    return ls

listA = [5,5,3,9,1,4,9,7,3]
result = insertionSort(listA)
print(result)
```

Output (with comments):

```
Outer loop. i is set to 1
[5, 5, 3, 9, 1, 4, 9, 7, 3] # 5 >= 5, so move onto the next loop without iterating
Outer loop. i is set to 2 
[5, 5, 3, 9, 1, 4, 9, 7, 3] # 3 < 5, so iterate i downwards until i = 0  
1
0
Outer loop. i is set to 3
[3, 5, 5, 9, 1, 4, 9, 7, 3] # 9 >= 5, so move onto the next loop without iterating
Outer loop. i is set to 4
[3, 5, 5, 9, 1, 4, 9, 7, 3] # 1 is the smallest of the sorted list, so iterate i downwards until i = 0
3
2
1
0
Outer loop. i is set to 5
[1, 3, 5, 5, 9, 4, 9, 7, 3] # 4 belongs between 3 and 5, so iterate i downwards until i = 2
4
3
2
Outer loop. i is set to 6 
[1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 9, 9, 7, 3] # 9 >= 9, so move onto the next loop without iterating
Outer loop. i is set to 7
[1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 9, 9, 7, 3] # 7 belongs between 5 and 9, so iterate i downwards until i = 5
6
5
Outer loop. i is set to 8
[1, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 9, 9, 3] # 3 belongs between 3 and 4, so iterate i downwards until i = 2
7
6
5
4
3
2
[1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 9, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't help to sort, it's there for the index to reach zero at some point. If you wouldn't add it, it would result in an infinite loop.

Comment: So, once the index reaches to 0, that means the list is sorted? But is has to come back to 0 or else it will run on forever.

Comment: Not exactly. It means that the entry of your list is on the right position. The list is sorted correctly, if the for loop is finished. Take a look into the while condition. If the list entry on position i-1 is bigger than the one on i (if it stops here, the current element is on the position in the list where it belongs) AND i > 0 (meaning if it's 0 or lower it stops) the two entries switch position. You basically iterate through your list and when it's finished, it returns the sorted list.